# Android MediaSession Callbacks. Interpreting double-click as SKIP_TO_NEXT on earphones

Tags: android, callback, media, double-click, headset

Mediasession callbacks allow us capture events like onPlay, onPause, onSkipToNext, onSkipToPrevious etc. And these work fine if I click the dedicated button on the bluetooth headset.

However, for earphones such as apple and beats, you have one single button near the mic for you to control all your playback. Single click refers to play/pause (works) and double-click refers to SkipToNext (doesn't work).

Do we have to handle the double-click ourselves for us to skip to next song? Or is there a way to trigger the right callback when double-clicked ?

Answer (score 2):

You can override the [MediaSession.Callback.onMediaButtonEvent](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/java/android/media/session/MediaSession.java#724) method and handle any specifics there (see the default implementation for an example of how to handle buttons and call the other callback methods appropriately).

It's reasonable that the platform should handle them for you, so I suggest that you also [open a bug](https://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html).

Answer (score 0):

it is simple all you need to do is use skip to next, in mediasession callback, and simply, put your players code to skip to next song, in this method, in callback, done, you can put play prev, or play pause to. I use a mediasession tracker, and media button receiver, if you go to github, Vanilla Music, download as zip, extract, and open in android studio some code is there you can copy modify, have done same in my app, hope this helps.